# Sending push notification to all clients?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

i configured my app push notification enabled.

should u collect the devicetoken id to my database? i dont send any particular message to some clients. i will inform all clients (push notification is accepted on device).

should i save the devietokenid in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken event?

is it possible to send push notif. to all clients (not collecting devicetokenid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, you are supposed to send the deviceToken to your server and store it there in some way. You can later use this deviceToken at any time to send a push notification to the device.

No, as far as I know, you always need to specify a device token to the APN server when sending a push message. There's no way to broadcast to all registered devices; you need to send multiple messages yourself to broadcast.